# Auto detect the browser and redirect

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, microsoft-edge

I'm still beginner. Is there a way to do this kind of redirect? As an example, I made the redirect link of the website and that website should be open in Microsoft Edge. If I open that file in IE or Chrome, it redirect to MS Edge. But if i open that redirect file in Ms Edge, it just showing Redirecting.

Is there a way to auto detect? What I mean is, I open that redirect file in IE and Chrome, it has to redirect and if I open in Ms Edge, it doesn't need to do redirect and just open the website on Edge by itself. Is there any resources for codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to check browser version. If Edge, doing nothing; if IE and Chrome, using `microsoft-edge:` URI scheme to open link in Edge.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>test page</div>
    <script>
        function detectbrowser() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            if (ua.indexOf("Edg") > 0) {  //Edge
                return;
            }
            else if (ua.indexOf("Trident") > 0 || ua.indexOf("Chrome") > 0) {  //IE or Chrome
                window.location = "microsoft-edge:" + window.location.href;
            }
        }
        detectbrowser();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i want to insert the redirect link by using window.location in the code you have given, where do i have to put?

Comment: I use google site as an example, you can do it like this: `window.location = "microsoft-edge: https://www.google.com";`.

Comment: thx and where do i put that window.location ? under else if or if

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the link in Edge when you open the page in IE or Chrome? If so, just replace this `window.location = "microsoft-edge:" + window.location.href;` with `window.location = "microsoft-edge: https://www.google.com";` under `else if`.

Comment: I see. yes, I want to open in Edge from IE. Also, if i open in Edge, will it work? my previous code is not working if i open in edge.

Comment: If you want to redirect to a link in Edge, you can put `window.location = "https://www.google.com";` under `if`, and delete `return;`.

Comment: thx a lote i will try. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Hello, ur helps actually works for me but there is 1 problem. I put window.location = "microsoft-edge: https://www.google.com"; under else if and It open Microsoft edge but it doesn't open google.com. May I know why?

Comment: Please pay attention there's no space between `microsoft-edge:` and the link. The code should be this: `window.location = "microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com"`.

Comment: it works now Thanks alot.